# SimpleCursorAdapter: отображение картинки, когда в базе нет данных

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос, связанный с SimpleCursorAdapter. У меня есть такой код:

```
  mCursor = managedQuery(
              ProceedsProvider.CONTENT_URI, mContent, null, null, null);
  mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.history, mCursor, 
            new String[] {DbHelper.NAME,ProceedsDbHelper.DATE}, 
            new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.date});
  setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

И разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
  >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Когда в базе есть данные, то они появляются на экране. С этим все нормально.
Если в базе нету данных, то просто пустое окно. Как сделать, что если в базе нету данных, то появляется картинка на экране, а если данные есть, то картинка пропадает и появляются данные.

Пробовал добавлять в разметку:

```
     <ImageView
     android:id="@android:id/empty"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/no" />
```

Но к сожалению - не помогло.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ( 16.10.2012 23:36):**
Файл main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/no" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Файл item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Файл MainActivity:

```
   private static final String[] mContent = new String[] {DbHelper.NAME,DbHelper.DATE};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mCursor = managedQuery(
            ProceedsProvider.CONTENT_URI, mContent, null, null, null);
          scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, mCursor, 
            new String[] {DbHelper.NAME,DbHelper.DATE}, 
            new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.date});
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

}
```

**Решено**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` должен иметь где-то `ListView` внутри которого он работает. Приведенный вами лэйаут это разметка строки списка, а не сам собственно список. Соответственно

```
<ImageView 
     android:id="@android:id/empty" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:src="@drawable/no" />
```

должен быть прикреплен к лэйауту списка.

**P.S.** [@gadfil](/users/9113/gadfil) слегка погорячился, `SimpleCursorAdapter` не deprecated, там объявлен устаревшим только 1 конструктор (кстати, именно тот который вы используете)

Comment: Переделал,теперь приложение вылетает... Новая версия в "ОБНОВЛЕНО ( 16.10.2012 23:36)".Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` устарел. Напиши лучше свой адаптер, в нем можешь и написать обработку пустой базы.

Answer (score 2):

У `ListView` есть метод `setEmptyView`